# Invalid Variable: drupal_private_key

Tags: configuration

I just updated my live Drupal install and now I receive the following notice in the admin:

Found one invalid variable

When I go to `/admin/reports/variablecheck` it shows that the variable `drupal_private_key` is invalid.

Is it safe to delete this key? Will it autogenerate? What does this key affect? Will I have to edit my cron to use a new key?

I tried using Google and this site but nothing seems to say what this key is or if it's okay to delete it. I have experienced this issue before a year ago but cannot remember the solution. I'm sure I am not the first person to experience this but intrigued I couldn't find a solution online.

Thanks for any insight on this issue.

**EDIT**

It appears the last time I had this issue I added the key to the settings file, including a drupal hash salt  variable (see [this post](https://www.drupal.org/node/2241311)). Everything was working fine until the update. This issue does not exist on DEV or STAGE, only on PROD